# Tuning keyboard for HP Omen 15 laptop

Tags: keyboard, hp

I've purchased HP Omen 15 notebook and installed Ubuntu 20.04 with KDE on it.

Everything works except 3 minor issues with keyboard.

Please, advice how to fix them.

1. <kbd>Calculator</kbd> button works with bugs. Calculator is opened very rarely. I've tried observing events with `xev` command, and have found that pressing this button produces sometimes many-many event with `XF86Calculator` key and sometimes - nothig.
2. <kbd>Omen</kbd> button doesn't work at all. I've read in forums that it is a dead button, supported in windows only. However, pressing it gives messages in `dmesg`:
   `[ 6931.025068] hp_wmi: Unknown event_id - 29 - 0x21a5`. So its not dead, probably, installing right driver may help. I understand that command center is supported only on Windows, but I could assign some other program to it.
3. Positions of <kbd>delete</kbd> and <kbd>pause</kbd> buttons are swapped in keyboard (see attached image). I'd like to remap them so that pressing <kbd>pause</kbd> would produce delete key events and vice versa.

[image]

Here is the output of `dmesg | grep input`:

```
[    1.080083] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
[    1.080114] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
[    1.080137] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
[    1.201495] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
[    1.469199] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:03/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4
[    1.654595] input: SYNA32A5:00 06CB:CE17 Mouse as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-SYNA32A5:00/0018:06CB:CE17.0001/input/input5
[    1.654751] input: SYNA32A5:00 06CB:CE17 Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-SYNA32A5:00/0018:06CB:CE17.0001/input/input6
[    1.654872] hid-generic 0018:06CB:CE17.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [SYNA32A5:00 06CB:CE17] on i2c-SYNA32A5:00
[    4.366866] input: HP WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input8
[    4.412494] input: HP Wide Vision HD Camera: HP Wi as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/input/input9
[    4.545854] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input10
[    4.545934] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input11
[    4.546008] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input12
[    4.546088] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input13
[    4.546164] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input14
[    4.546258] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input15
[    4.547361] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:    inputs:
[    4.550677] input: SYNA32A5:00 06CB:CE17 Mouse as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-SYNA32A5:00/0018:06CB:CE17.0001/input/input16
[    4.551919] input: SYNA32A5:00 06CB:CE17 Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-SYNA32A5:00/0018:06CB:CE17.0001/input/input17
[    4.552036] hid-multitouch 0018:06CB:CE17.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [SYNA32A5:00 06CB:CE17] on i2c-SYNA32A5:00
[    4.592745] input: HD-Audio Generic Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.6/sound/card2/input19
[    4.592837] input: HD-Audio Generic Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.6/sound/card2/input20
[  599.371063] input: KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.4/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/0003:0458:0186.0002/input/input21
[  599.371352] hid-generic 0003:0458:0186.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse] on usb-0000:06:00.4-2/input0
[  599.371405] usbhid 5-2:1.1: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Struggle with <kbd>Calculator</kbd> is still going on. I've submitted a separate question about it ([Troubles with Calculator key on HP notebook](https://askubuntu.com/q/1336575/625814)). Currently I suppose that the issue is somewhere in xkb subsystem.

   UPDATE: Finished. Thanks to "nameless" helper! :) See the link above.
2. [This repository](https://github.com/pelrun/hp-omen-linux-module) contains an updated driver for HP WMI, that enables four-zone keyboard highlight and maps <kbd>Omen</kbd> key to `XF86Launch(6)` key. Thanks James Churchill for his efforts!
3. Swapping <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Pause</kbd> is done by file `$HOME/.Xmodmap` with the following content

   ```
   keycode 119 = Pause Break Pause Break
   keycode 127 = Delete NoSymbol Delete
   ```

   These instructions are determined using the following algorithm.

   1. Determine correct keycodes (119 and 127 above) with `showkey -k`. Run `sudo showkey -k` and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> then <kbd>Pause</kbd>. That program has printed 111 keycode for <kbd>Delete</kbd> and 119 for <kbd>Pause</kbd> on my machine.
   2. Add 8 to them and put in that file. I'm not sure, but value of 8 is probably obtained from the output of `xmodmap -pk`. First line of its output shows 8 on my PC, which is min keycode.
   3. Figure out original mappings of these keys by running `xmodmap -pke`. For example original mapping for <kbd>Delete</kbd> key on my PC was

   ```
   $ xmodmap -pke | grep 119
   keycode 119 = Delete NoSymbol Delete
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer to your question, I managed to swap the pause and delete keys for the HP Omen 15 https://gist.github.com/kellpossible/d2d7992b4aa6b9214577596843d307b6

Comment: And I've managed to make Omen key to generate XF86Calculator event.

Comment: Could you add the instructions to your answer here?

Comment: Do these changes survive package update?

Comment: I don't know, but it hasn't broken so far.