# Troubles with Calculator key on HP notebook

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, udev, media-buttons

I've got a new notebook HP Omen 15, manufactured in 2020.
I has <kbd>Calculator</kbd> key, and I cannot get it launching calculator in Ubuntu 20.04.

When I press <kbd>Calculator</kbd> key, nothing happens. I also cannot assign a shortcut to that key in the respective configuration program from the desktop environment. I've tried KDE with Plasma and Gnome shell (I suppose it is launched if I choose "Ubuntu" session on login screen of a display manager). Those programs invite "Press a desired key" but don't see  <kbd>Calculator</kbd> key presses.

I've tried debugging situation with `xev` and `showkey` utilities.

If I run `xev` and press <kbd>Calculator</kbd> I see insanely many messages about pressing and releasing `XF86Calculator` key:

```
...
KeyRelease event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
root 0x29e, subw 0x0, time 52918, (151,-96), root:(151,806),
state 0x14, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
root 0x29e, subw 0x0, time 52918, (151,-96), root:(151,806),
state 0x14, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
root 0x29e, subw 0x0, time 52958, (151,-96), root:(151,806),
state 0x14, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
root 0x29e, subw 0x0, time 52958, (151,-96), root:(151,806),
state 0x14, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
root 0x29e, subw 0x0, time 52999, (151,-96), root:(151,806),
state 0x14, keycode 148 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XFilterEvent returns: False
...
```

Then I press Ctrl-C to stop it.
If I run `xev` again, it doesn't show any events on <kbd>Calculator</kbd> key.
If I run `dmesg`, it shows messages like `[ 5685.955273] kauditd_printk_skb: 46 callbacks suppressed`. Probably this key still generates press-release events, but the kernel suppresses them.

Probably this is the reason of the bug.

If I run `showkey`, it always shows scan codes and key codes, if I press <kbd>Calculator</kbd> key:

```
$ sudo showkey -s
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
0x9c
0xe0 0x21
0x1d
^Ccaught signal 2, cleaning up...
0xe0 0x21
```

```
$ sudo showkey -k
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode  28 release
keycode 140 press
keycode  29 press
^Ccaught signal 2, cleaning up...
```

Overall, it looks like that key is a normal media key that is correctly mapped to `XF86Calculator`.

So, could you give me any clues how to get it working?

I am ready to provide any additional information about my notebook and OS.

I also think that I could try to fix that bug myself. However, currently I have no idea which module to debug.

**Update** Have found that logging in and out sometimes restores Calculator key. For example, if I run KDE Plasma, press Calculator key, then log out and run Ubuntu on Wayland, then I can lauch calculator once more.

**Update2** [Ubuntu hotkeys troubleshooting](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Troubleshooting) wiki page contains description of the case that seems to be exactly mine. Case 4.b - "if there are too many keypress events then you need to determine where they are being duplicated." However, that's all.
So, I'd be grateful for any clues on how to determine that.

**Update3** I've tried two times to reach Christopher Peñalver, author of that wiki page, however, haven't received any answer to my mails. Digging further, I've found that the issue could be in udev rules for my keyboard. Have submitted bug report to Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1929345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it has been fixed! Thanks to someone on Github!

The issue was in udev database, PR fixing it is merged, hopefully, it will work after one of next updates.

Solution is here

https://github.com/pelrun/hp-omen-linux-module/issues/9#issuecomment-936474113

One needs to add following lines to the file `/usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`

```
# HP Omen 15
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnHP:pnOMENLaptop15*:pvr*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_a1=!calc
```

**Update**

Better solution until fresh version of HWDB appears in the packages is to put those lines in the file `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/70-keyboard.hwdb`

Then run `sudo systemd-hwdb update`

These lines have been included in [systemd v250](https://github.com/systemd/systemd-stable/blob/a420d71793bcbc1539a63be60f83cdc14373ea4a/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb#L714).

Currently (05 Jan 2022) version of systemd on my KUbuntu 20.04 is 245.

**Update2**

03 Jan 2023, package udev, version 249.11, includes that line.